# enamelled pot with a chip on the outside on the bottom

Tags: cookware, pot

I have an enamelled pot with a chip on the outside on the bottom. This isn't a problem, is it?  It is about an inch long and maybe an eighth of an inch wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be a big problem.

Just be careful not let the exposed area rust,

Clean and dry thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think so. But,it is always good to ask.